# Cannot change authsetting of Web Apps with new Authentication feature enabled from Azure Resource Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-authentication

I am trying to change `additionalLoginParams` of authsetting in Web Apps with [new Authentication feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/updated-app-service-authentication-portal-experience-is-now-generally-available/) enabled, as shown in the image below.

[image]

But when I clicked `PUT` to save the change, it fails with an error shown in the image below.
Does this mean I have to use a legacy one in order to change authsetting from Azure Resource Explorer, or is there any other place to change the setting for new version?

[image]

Comment: Actually you can change it on the Azure portal => your app service => Authentication blade

Comment: Thanks. But where in Authentication blade?

Comment: I found a link to edit Authentication, token store, and allowed external redirect urls but nothing else. Where can I edit additionalLoginParams from the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue, as per [Updating the configuration version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#updating-the-configuration-version):

> Migration to V2 will disable management of the App Service Authentication / Authorization feature for your application through some clients, such as its existing experience in the Azure portal, Azure CLI, and Azure PowerShell. This cannot be reversed.

Even it does not mention `Resource Explorer`, but it should also be included, because when you set the `authsettings` with Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell, they essentially calls  the REST API to do that, which the same as the `Resource Explorer` does.

Since this cannot be reversed, so if you want to set the `additionalLoginParams`, your option is to create a new web app, configure the auth in `Authentication (classic)` blade in the portal first, then set  `additionalLoginParams` in `Resource Explorer`, at last upgrade it to V2, it will work fine.

Comment: thank you for your confirmation. 
So at the moment, there is still some use cases for v1 Authentication...

Comment: fwiw I found a way to do it and posted it on serverfault earlier: https://serverfault.com/a/1064040/126699

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [workaround](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13246#issuecomment-930854968) for downgrading the function app's `configVersion` using Azure CLI. (Although I am not sure if Az Powershell equivalent exist while writing this answer.):

`az webapp auth config-version revert --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group myrg --name my-fx-app`

`az webapp auth config-version show --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group myrg --name my-fx-app`